I am Attempting to local port forward a website on a LXC to view on host web browser but getting "Connection was reset"
I have a CodeIgniter app that is hosted on a LXC container at IP 10.0.3.200 with user name ci
I use the following local port forwarding method in separate terminal:
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 ci@10.0.3.200
Also tried:
ssh -L 8080:10.0.3.200:8080 ci@10.0.3.200
In a separate terminal I ssh into ci@10.0.3.200 and execute Codeigniter to test app:
$ php spark serve

CodeIgniter v4.4.4 Command Line Tool - Server Time: 2024-07-07 16:50:00 UTC+00:00

CodeIgniter development server started on http://localhost:8080
Press Control-C to stop.
[Sun Jul  7 16:50:00 2024] PHP 8.1.29 Development Server (http://localhost:8080) started

I browse to localhost:8080 and get the following message:
"Connection was reset"

I am rebuilding a CodeIgniter app from Version 2 to Version 4 and so I expect there to be errors but I also expect a regular page with errors or a different message on the web page.
Am I using the tunneling method in the correct manner?

I can still view the page by browsing to the server with following command:
php spark serve --port 8088 --host 10.0.3.200
Browse to 10.0.3.200:8088
